# Ansible, run several arguments in ssh-args

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm trying to run a playbook in ansible and want to pass two arguments in ssh-args, but looks like it's failing.

The arguments I want to pass are:

- proxycommand
- StrictHostKeyChecking

```
ansible-playbook provisioning/ec2.yml -i ec2.py --private-key KEY.pem --ssh-common-args '-o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p -i KEY.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XX"' --skip-tags=ansible -vvvv
```

But looks it fails, as the connection never occurs, if I run it only with `proxycommand` it works, only that I need to type yes for host verification process.

```
ansible-playbook provisioning/ec2.yml -i ec2.py --private-key KEY.pem --ssh-common-args '-o " proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p -i KEY.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XX"' --skip-tags
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of Ansible-core are you using? (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31321)